# Ajax can't work in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, shopping-cart

Base on ['Agile Web Development with Rails, Third Edition'](http://pragprog.com/book/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails), I created a cart with Ajax, but Ajax isn't working for me. My code is as follows:

**/store/index.html.erb**：

```
<%= form_tag({:action=>'add_to_cart', :id=>product}, :remote=>true ) do %>
<%= submit_tag "Add to Cart" %>
<% end %>
```

**/layouts/store.html.erb**：

```
<head>
...
<%= javascript_include_tag :defults %>
...
</head>
```

**/controllers/store_controller.rb**：

```
def add_to_cart
...
respond_to do |format|
format.js
end
...
end
```

**add_to_cart.js.rjs**

```
page.replace_html("cart",:partial => "cart", :object=>@cart)
```

Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

RJS isn't a part of Rails any more. You can use jQuery instead without any additional download required: just don't use the `.rjs` at the end. If you know CoffeeScript, it's also available here: name your file `*.coffee` and you are done. Also you can name it `*.coffee.erb` to allow the ERb to preprocess you file but this feature is allowed by default even for simple `*.coffee`-files.

**UPD:**

```
page.replace_html("cart",:partial => "cart", :object=>@cart)
```

Should become:

```
$("#cart").html("<%= j render(@cart) %>")
```

Comment: according to soundar's advice, it can run. but there is a problem: I must refresh the whole page and then the cart can be shown.

Answer (score 0):

js templates are named as name.js.erb in Rails 3.

Let me assume you are going to replace "cart" div in ajax call and you have jQuery.
create add_to_cart.js.erb with the following code.

```
$("#cart").replaceWith('<%=escape_javascript(render :partial => 'cart', :object=>@cart) %>');
```

Comment: Since when `escape_javascript` accepts `:partial` and `:object`? :-) I'm not a fan of ready-to-use advices (a user should think a little) but you seem mislead the author so I updated my answer.

Comment: That was a typo I have missed render in my code. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Base on soundar's advice, the ajax has not still worked. the log show:Started POST "/store/add_to_cart/3" for ... , Processing by StoreController#add_to_cart as HTML ..., Completed 406 Not Acceptable

Comment: Thank you soundar ! according to your code, I modified the store.html.erb, change the javascript_include_tag from ":defaults" to "application". the ajax can run. but there is a litter problem that can't automatically update, I must refresh the whole page. could you give me suggestion ? thx!

Comment: are you getting the response html via ajax?

Comment: nothing. in index.html.erb, my code: <%= button_to "Add to Cart, { :action => :add_to_cart, :id => product}, :remote => true" %>

Comment: add alert("js erb template rendered"); in your add_to_cart.js.erb and check alert is raised when you click Add to Cart button.

Comment: Yes, the alert is raised when I click "Add to Cart" button

Comment: @soundar, in the console I see these information below：
Render store/_cart_item.html.erb
Render store/_cart.html.erb
Render store/add_to_cart.js.erb